# Correct way showing remote website content on own domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, dom

I'm interested how websites like adf.ly showing remote website content with their own content on the bottom like "skip ad" in their case website he advertiser have placed for promotion ?
I need to show affiliate page but getting from Firefox/Chrome warning that I can't due security reasons.
Using code like this:

`<iframe src="https://cnn.com" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0">`

However I see that using an JS code which is obfuscated on their website, they able to put it out. I'm a completely nooby with JS, is there an way to do it by not hacking browsers without hundreds bytes of code, do they deconstruct whole website somehow and then putting it over back for users using JS or other language ;-) ? Any directions would be nice, maybe there's an much easier way to do it over PHP maybe, I'm not asking for code ofcourse maybe someone know an library. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think adf.ly lets people put adverts over their own webpages, not pages of other people.

Comment: Well , I bought traffic from them like 5 years back and they delivered it for me, since I'm from small country I seen my website myself :) I'm also got attack on my site, when some mirrored my site on unknown host and it looked completely the same.

Comment: Can you give one example where adf.ly is shown over a webpage where it itself is not integrated into that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you tagged php in question, the easiest way would be
`$copied = file_get_contents("https://link-to-site");`
`echo $copied;`

Comment: Thank you stillKonfuzed. I just ran the code and the output for me is ok in my case, not sure about all elements will dig a bit more on this, that have solved my problem, thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the https://cnn.com site and it uses a header called [content-security-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy). In it they specify the option:

```
frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.cnn.com:* http://*.cnn.com:* https://*.cnn.io:* http://*.cnn.io:* *.turner.com:* courageousstudio.com;
```

This specifies valid parents that may embed a page using `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, or `<applet>`.

Your browser clearly complies with this header.

There are ways to circumvent this, but this can get complex, and I am not sure I should help you with this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it meanwhile.